# Moto E XT1022 Downgrade to Kitkat Issue

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.1-lollipop, downgrade, motorola-moto-e

I've Moto E with Lollipop 5.1 updated. This Version of OS gives me troubles like Disables Networks, Doesnot go in Wifi Settings etc., since a week ago. Before that, its working good only. Warranty for this mobile also expired. So that, i have tried to install my Older 4.4.4 kitkat Version to my Moto E using this Tutorial.
[Downgrade from Lollipop to KitKat for Moto E](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7S5WmlPgrI)

I've done all those steps mentioned in the downgrade process. I've used the some resource files mentioned in that youtube page. But problem arised in the final process of Downgrade.

After formatting process, it gives me error that "Invalid Signed Image" & "Preflash Validation Failed". I Could not find out any solution for this issue. Now my phone has no OS. SO Can anyone suggest me to Boot OS to my Phone?

Any suggestions will be greatly helpful to me..

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to downgrade your moto e to Kitkat. Then there are two option, one is install stock kitkat rom by this [method](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2759495) and another one is flash a custom recovery like CWM or TWRP in your phone and then flash a zip distribution of a ROM that you like. But i'll recommend to follow second option because if you go for first option, then as you already mentioned that your current OS is Lollipop which updates the bootloader accordingly and if you go for kitkat then the bootloader may cause problem not always but there are chances and I have bricked my phone this way.Assuming you have moto e first gen. follow this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2754486) to install TWRP custom recovery.You can find your phone's flashable firmware from [here](http://motorola-condor.blogspot.in/p/xt-1022motorola-stock-firmware-romxt.html). Do it with caution, hope you get your phone alive again.